# React Bootstrap Select multiple showing error in Formik as it is expecting a string but returns array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, formik, yup

React Bootstrap Select multiple showing error in Formik as it is expecting a string but returns array

Error: Warning: The `value` prop supplied to  must be an array if `multiple` is true.

Check the render method of `FormControl`.

I believe that the error is on FormControl.d.ts inside Formik because it only accepts a string as a type

This is the Interface that Formik exposes

```
    export interface FormControlProps {
      innerRef?: React.LegacyRef<this>;
      size?: 'sm' | 'lg';
      plaintext?: boolean;
      readOnly?: boolean;
      disabled?: boolean;
      value?: string; // <-- it should also receive string[] ?
      onChange?: React.FormEventHandler<this>;
      type?: string;
      id?: string;
      isValid?: boolean;
      isInvalid?: boolean;
    }
```

This is my file from where I'm trying to get the expertise

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Container, Row, Col, Card, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Formik } from 'formik';
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import * as Yup from 'yup';

    const ExpertSignUpSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        expertise: Yup.array()
            .of(Yup.string())
            .min(1)
            .required('Required'),
    });

    const ExpertSignUpPage: React.FC = () => (
        <Container fluid>
            <Row>
                <Col md={4} />
                <Col>
                    <CardWrapper>
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Header as="h5">Expert Registration</Card.Header>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Formik
                                    initialValues={{
                                        expertise: [''],
                                    }}
                                    validationSchema={ExpertSignUpSchema}
                                    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                                        console.log(values);
                                        setSubmitting(false);
                                    }}
                                    render={({
                                        values,
                                        errors,
                                        touched,
                                        handleBlur,
                                        handleChange,
                                        handleSubmit,
                                        isSubmitting,
                                    }) => (
                                        <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                                <Form.Control
                                                    as="select"
                                                    multiple
                                                    name="expertise"
                                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                    value={values.expertise} // <--- it should allow an array of strings, currently the code won't compile or won't update the form value as it has multiple in the form control
                                                    isValid={touched.expertise && !errors.expertise}
                                                    isInvalid={!!errors.expertise}
                                                >
                                                    <option value="YOGA">Yoga</option>
                                                    <option value="PERSONAL_TRAINER">Personal Trainer</option>
                                                    <option value="LIFE_COACH">Life Coach</option>
                                                    <option value="NUTRITIONIST">Nutritionist</option>
                                                </Form.Control>
                                            </Form.Group>
                                            <Button
                                                variant="outline-primary"
                                                type="submit"
                                                block={true}
                                                disabled={isSubmitting}
                                            >
                                                Register
                                            </Button>
                                        </Form>
                                    )}
                                />
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </CardWrapper>
                </Col>
                <Col md={4} />
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );

    export default connect(
        null,
        null,
    )(ExpertSignUpPage);

    const CardWrapper = styled.div`
        margin-top: 5rem;
    `;
```

For some reason I'm unable to even get the values in the array when I update the the definition file to string | string[].

Comment: Which version of `react-bootstrap` are you using?

Comment: The problem is not with `Formik`. The file that you mention `FormControl.d.ts` is not exposed by `Formik`. It is a part of `react-bootstrap` package. `FormControl`'s usage varies depending on `react-bootstrap`'s version.

Answer (score -1):

```
It took two days to make it error-free... and I had hoped this would be work at your end..    



import React from 'react';
    import { Container, Row, Col, Image, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import style from '../styles/Contact.module.css';
    import { Formik, Field} from 'formik';
    import * as Yup from 'yup';
    
    
    const dropdown=[
        {
            key:"Select an option",
            value:""
        },
        {
            key:"Option 1",
            value:"option1"
        },
        {
            key:"Option 2",
            value:"option2"
        },
        {
            key:"Option 3",
            value:"option3"
        }
    ]
    
    
    
    
    // RegEx for phone number validation
    const phoneRegExp = /^(\+?\d{0,4})?\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{4}\)?)?$/
    
    // Schema for yup
    const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string()
            .min(2, "*Names must have at least 2 characters")
            .max(30, "*Names can't be longer than 30 characters")
            .required("*Name is required"),
        email: Yup.string()
            .email("*Must be a valid email address")
            .max(100, "*Email must be less than 100 characters")
            .required("*Email is required"),
        phone: Yup.string()
        .min(10, "*Names can't be longer than 10 numbers")
            .matches(phoneRegExp, "*Phone number is not valid")
            .required("*Phone number required"),
          
        msg: Yup.string()
            .min(2, "*Messages must have at least 2 characters")
            .max(250, "*Messages can't be longer than 250 characters")
            .required("*Messages is required"),
        
              selectionOption: Yup.string()
                // .of(Yup.string())
                // .min(1)
                .required('Required'), 
    });
    
    const Signup = () => {

        return (
            <>
   
                <Formik
                  initialValues={{ name: "", email: "", phone: "", msg: "",selectionOption:"" }}
                    validationSchema={validationSchema}
                    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
                        // When button submits form and form is in the process of submitting, submit button is disabled
                       console.log(values)
                        setSubmitting(true);
    
                        // Simulate submitting to database, shows us values submitted, resets form
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                            resetForm();
                            setSubmitting(false);
                        }, 500);
                    }}
                >
                    {({ values,
                        errors,
                        touched,
                        handleChange,
                        handleBlur,
                        handleSubmit,
                        isSubmitting }) => (
    
                        <Form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete="off" name="contact" method="POST" >
                            <Row className="mb-5">
                                <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={12}>
                                    <Form.Group controlId="formName">
                                        <Form.Label className="form_label" >FullName</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            type="text"
                                            name="name"
                                            placeholder="Full Name"
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                                            value={values.name}
                                            className={touched.name && errors.name ? "has-error" : null}
                                        />
                                        {touched.name && errors.name ? (
                                            <div className="error-message">{errors.name}</div>
                                        ) : null}
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Col>
    
    
                                <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={12}>
                                    <Form.Group>
                                        <Form.Label className="form_label" >Number</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            type="text"
                                            name="phone"
                                            placeholder="Phone"
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                                            value={values.phone}
                                            className={touched.phone && errors.phone ? "has-error" : null}
                                        />
                                        {touched.phone && errors.phone ? (
                                            <div className="error-message">{errors.phone}</div>
                                        ) : null}
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
    
    
                            <Row className="mb-5">
                                <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={12}>
                                    <Form.Group>
                                        <Form.Label className="form_label" >Email</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            type="text"
                                            name="email"
                                            placeholder="Email"
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                                            value={values.email}
                                            className={touched.email && errors.email ? "has-error" : null}
                                        />
                                        {touched.email && errors.email ? (
                                            <div className="error-message">{errors.email}</div>
                                        ) : null}
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Col>
                                <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={12}>
                                {/* <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example">
          <option>Open this select menu</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
        </Form.Select> */}
                    <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
    
           
                
                
              
                    <Form.Label>Example select</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control as="select" name ="selectionOption" onChange={handleChange}
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}  value={values.selectionOption}
                                            className={touched.selectionOption && errors.selectionOption ? "has-error" : null}
                                            >
    {
        dropdown.map(drop=>{return(
        <option key={drop.value} value={drop.value}>
            {drop.key}
    
    </option>
            )
        }
        )
    }
        </Form.Control>
        {/* <ErrorMessage name="selectionOption"></ErrorMessage> */}
    
        {touched.selectionOption && errors.selectionOption ? (
                                            <div className="error-message">{errors.selectionOption}</div>
                                        ) : null} 
       
    
    
    
    
    
    
                        {/* <Form.Label>Example select</Form.Label>
                        <Field as="select" name ="selectionOption" onChange={handleChange}
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}  value={values.selectionOption}
                                            style={{ display: "block" }}
                                            // isValid={touched.selectionOption && !errors.selectionOption}
                                            // isInvalid={!errors.selectionOption}
    
                                            className={touched.selectionOption && errors.selectionOption ? "has-error" : null}
                                        
                                            
                                        
                                            
                                            >
                            
                            <option className='text-muted'>---</option>
          <option value="ortho">ortho</option>
          <option value="pedri">pedri</option>
          <option value="crown">crown</option>
                         
          </Field>
          {touched.selectionOption && errors.selectionOption ? (
                                            <div className="error-message">{errors.selectionOption}</div>
                                        ) : null} */}
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                            </Row>
                            <Row className="mb-5">
                                <Col lg={12} md={12} sm={12}>
                                    <Form.Group controlId="formmsg">
                                        <Form.Label>Messages :</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            type="text"
                                            name="msg"
                                            as="textarea" rows={4}
                                            placeholder="Query / Feedback"
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                                            value={values.msg}
                                            className={touched.msg && errors.msg ? "has-error" : null}
                                        />
                                        {touched.msg && errors.msg ? (
                                            <div className="error-message">{errors.msg}</div>
                                        ) : null}
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Col>
                                
                            </Row>
    
                            <Button type="submit" className={style.customizeBtn} name="contact" id="contact" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                                <Image src="img/send.png" className={style.imgBtn} />
                                <span className={style.titleBtn}>Submit</span>
                            </Button>
                        </Form>
                    )}
    
                </Formik>
    
            </>
        )
    }
    export default Signup;
```

Comment: Here, you can find react-bootstrap all input(form-control) along with formik and yup validation package @Nathan

Comment: I have no vested interest in this question, I'm very familiar with Formik. I'm just advising that a helpful answer on Stack Overflow should contain a summary and context, explaining what you did and why, not just a block of code. I would advise editing it.